# Preparing single sentence per line document from plain text

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to create new version of documment from general plain text such that each of the 
new version of document contains one sentence per line. It means , each line of text contains sequnce of strings ending up with `.`. Could you please suggest me some sample scripts for it?

```
 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
 Now the earth was formless and empty.  Darkness was on the surface
 of the deep.  God's Spirit was hovering over the surface
 of the waters.
```

Into

```
 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
 Now the earth was formless and empty.
 Darkness was on the surface of the deep.
 God's Spirit was hovering over the surface of the waters.
```

Comment: I tried some scripts for reading lines from text .But those consider a sentence for a sequnce of strings before newline.

Comment: Please post the source to the scripts that you have tried so far... that way, we can tweak what you've done up to now, rather than writing something from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = "[.] *"; ORS = ".\n"} {gsub(" *\n *", " "); if ($0 !~ /^ +$/) print}'
```

Separate the text at each period followed by spaces, if any (`RS`).

The output of each line will be followed by a period and newline (`ORS`).

Substitute a space for each newline and any surrounding spaces (`gsub()`).

If the line does not consist solely of spaces, print it.

You can change the places that show a space followed by an asterisk or plus sign to be `[[:blank:]]` (followed by the asterisk or plus) if you want to accommodate tabs as well as spaces.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\n\Z/ /; s/(\.)\s*/$1\n/g' infile
```

Output:

```
In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
Now the earth was formless and empty.
Darkness was on the surface of the deep.
God's Spirit was hovering over the surface of the waters.
```

Answer (score 2):

As a start, try a combination of `tr` and `sed`

```
$ cat input
They're selling postcards of the hanging. They're painting the passports brown. The beauty parlor is filled with sailors. The circus is in town.


$ cat input | tr '.' '\n' | sed 's/$/\./;s/[    ]*//'
They're selling postcards of the hanging.
They're painting the passports brown.
The beauty parlor is filled with sailors.
The circus is in town.
```

Comment: It's a start, but it won't work with the OP's sample input without some refinement.